# spark-submit DependencyUtils: Local jar does not exists, skipping

Tags: scala, apache-spark, classpath, spark-submit, fatjar

Context: **Windows 10/Linux Ubuntu 8 LTS**

Spark: **3.3.0 (spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3)**

I'm running spark-submit with a fat jar, but I receive a "jar does not exists" from DependencyUtils, even if the JAR is in place. As a consequence the mainClass is not found

Command:

```
bin\spark-submit --verbose --master local --class <packagename>.Application
--executor-memory 800m C:\<path to project>\target\scala-
2.12\ProjectName.jar
```

The result is

```
Using properties file: null
Parsed arguments:
  master                  local
  deployMode              null
  executorMemory          800m
  executorCores           null
  totalExecutorCores      null
  propertiesFile          null
  driverMemory            null
  driverCores             null
  driverExtraClassPath    null
  driverExtraLibraryPath  null
  driverExtraJavaOptions  null
  supervise               false
  queue                   null
  numExecutors            null
  files                   null
  pyFiles                 null
  archives                null
  mainClass               <packagename>.Application
  primaryResource         file:/C:<path to project>target/scala-2.12/ProjectName.jar
  name                    <packagename>.Application
  childArgs               []
  jars                    null
  packages                null
  packagesExclusions      null
  repositories            null
  verbose                 true

Spark properties used, including those specified through
 --conf and those from the properties file null:



Main class:
<packagename>.Application
Arguments:

Spark config:
(spark.app.name,<packagename>.Application)
(spark.app.submitTime,1664225037825)
(spark.jars,file:/C:<path to project>/target/scala-2.12/ProjectName.jar)
(spark.master,local)
(spark.submit.deployMode,client)
(spark.submit.pyFiles,)
Classpath elements:
file:/C:<path to project>/target/scala-2.12/PrrojectName.jar


22/09/26 22:43:57 WARN DependencyUtils: Local jar C:<path to project>\target\scala-2.12\ProjectName.jar does not exist, skipping.
Error: Failed to load class <packagename>.Application.
22/09/26 22:43:57 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Lorenzo